# Does using \font cause problems?

Tags: fonts

While editing a LaTeX file in Vim with the [LaTeX-Box](https://github.com/LaTeX-Box-Team/LaTeX-Box) and [syntastic](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic) plugins and compiling using XeLaTeX, I got this warning:

```
Don't use "\font" in LaTeX documents
```

for these two lines:

```
\font\ttfstandard Ubuntu at12pt
\font\ttfbold "Ubuntu Bold" at12pt
```

Is `\font` deprecated or otherwise harmful? If not, why would I have got this message? What should I use instead?

Comment: Yes, it's deprecated. Load `fontspec` instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, using `\font` in LaTeX is deprecated. The reason is very simple: try the following sample file.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\font\ttfstandard="Ubuntu" at 12pt
\font\ttfbold="Ubuntu Bold" at 12pt

\begin{document}

\section{A title with an {\ttfstandard Ubuntu} word}

Some text and an {\ttfstandard Ubuntu} word.

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you clearly see, the font doesn't honor the size changing commands.

Try instead the following example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setsansfont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Ubuntu}

\begin{document}

\section{A title with an \textsf{Ubuntu} word}

Some text and an \textsf{Ubuntu} word.

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can see that the size is honored and also that boldface is automatically selected in the section title.

You may want to have `Scale=MatchUppercase`, which would give

[image]

The choice depends much on how you want to use the sans serif type. If in isolation, `MatchUppercase` may be preferable; if interspersed with serif type, I'd go with `MatchLowercase`.

Comment: Thanks. Do `fontenc` and `fontspec` work well together? Or does that warrant a different question?

Comment: You do not need fontenc nor inputenc with xelatex. Just load fontspec